# Open-source software that allows me to keep track of working hours

Tags: open-source, osx, time-management

I am looking for a software that allows me to keep track of:

- when I started and finished working per day
- total hours worked per month
- average hours worked per day per month
- optional: average hours worked per day per year, per whole time
  period measured
- optional: ability to generate some graphs, figures from this data would be nice

GNU-ish (open-source) software recommendations would be especially good!

Right now I am trying to do this in LibreOffice Calc with my own formulas, but it is difficult and tedious to design, and I am not sure if my formulas really do what I think they are doing.

**Clarification**: I am looking for a stand-alone software for Mac OS, not a web-app.

Comment: I removed the gratis tag, which someone edited in, because according to the description of the gratis tag, the open-source tag is actually the one which fits better here.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a web-app to achieve this: Time & Bill - https://app.timeandbill.de/

It is free (at the time of answering this ;)) & it meets 1) 2) 3) points that you mentioned in your questions.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my original question, I meant I am searching for a software for Mac OS, not a website.